# How to make IIS Rewrite URL working?

Tags: asp.net, iis

i tried to redirect user enter url **http://example:917/** to **http://example:917/View/index.aspx** automatic and i use Rewrite Url feature
from IIS and this is what I set in iis

[Please click to see what i set in IIS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8v697.png)

when i try enter http://example:917/ i got 403 error that means rewrite from iis not working. Please help Thank you so much

Comment: have you tried with default url

Comment: yes tried already it work ex. Views/index.aspx, and if and then when redirect page in jquery result -> Views/Views/next.aspx

Comment: i want first time user enter http:localhost:112 then redirect -> http:localhost:112/Views/index.aspx

Comment: i update information please see again

Comment: Learn carefully Microsoft documentation please, which has tons of examples. You just used your own imagination, and filled wrong values in Match URL's Pattern and HTTP_HOST.

Comment: I'm done for this